# In what manner, rotation is 90 degrees here?

Tags: html, css

In the code below, the button with close id, is rotated 90 degrees. But I don't get how that button moved 90 degrees and with respect to what origin. `transform-origin: top left;` But top left of what element?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.circle-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #ff7979;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  /*   border-radius: 50%; */
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.circle button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
}

.circle button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.circle button#open {
  left: 60%;
}

.circle button#close {
  top: 60%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e057ae8bc6.js"></script>
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <button id="close">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    <button id="open">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is not clear about [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)?

Comment: I got it after I looked more carefully. Top-left is that button's top-left. The button has been stretched vertically by height property. I got confused because in my mind I was viewing button element as having an equal size of icon element inside. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @grshvetal it will be better if you added your answer to here and close the question or keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The top-left is of that button's top-left. I button has been stretched vertically by using height property as well as pushed from the top using absolute positioning. I got confused because, in my mind, I was viewing button element as having an equal size of icon element inside.